# Popupmenu wont work in java?

Tags: java, swing, listener, popupmenu

i am constructing a word processor program as an assignment for my Java class in school and i am having a really hard time getting the popupmenu to work when i right click on my text area. I have already constructed the popup menu and have my textarea listening to my popuplistener and i have overridden the mouse pressed and mouse released functions with

```
class popupframe extends JFrame{
JMenuItem copy;
JMenuItem paste;
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
JPopupMenu pop;
popupframe(){
Container cpane = getContentPane();
setSize(300 , 300);
setLocation(300, 300);
setTitle("Test");
JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
copy = new JMenuItem("copy");
paste = new JMenuItem("paste");
textarea = new JTextArea("something goes here", 5, 5);
pop.add(copy);
pop.add(paste);
PopupListener popuplistener = new PopupListener();
textarea.addMouseListener(popuplistener);

}

class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter{
    public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        popit(e);
    }
    public void MouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        popit(e);
    }
    private void popit(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
            pop.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
}
```

I cannot see why it is not working but perhaps i am missing something crucial, please help!! much appreciated

Comment: *"I cannot see why it is not working"* - Neither can we. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Also, consider using [`JComponent#serComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)) and let it take care of the nitty gritty details

Comment: thank for the reply, i edited my code so you could get a clearer picture of what im looking to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `@Override` annotation to the methods you think your are overriding...

```
class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
        popit(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void MouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
        popit(e);
    }
```

You will now find that this fails to compile, but why?  Because Java is case sensitive, and by convention, method names start with a lower case character

You'll find that something like...

```
class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        popit(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        popit(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        popit(e);
    }

    private void popit(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            pop.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

will work better.  But having said that, you'll generally find

```
textarea.setComponentPopupMenu(pop);
```

significantly easier and less error prone (and it won't cause a `NullPointerException` like your example code will.

Comment: i tried the code you provided but it threw an exception, however when i tried the setComponentPopupMenu(pop) menthod it worked. Thanks alot! although im curious as to why my method didnt work, ill just implement the method i learned from you, i appreciate the help ! :)

Comment: It's not my code, it's yours.  You define `pop` as an instance field `JPopupMenu pop;`, but intiialise it as a local variable in your constructor, `JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();` . I did say you'd get a NPE based on your example code ;)